# How to intialize an empty C array using pointers and fulfill it the same way

Tags: c

I'm trying to solve this following question: (I'm new to coding)

Given an array of integers nums and an integer target, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to target.

I don't know how to proceed though cuz I don't remember how to return the array values I'm filling this array:
I appreciate any help

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int* twoSum(int* nums, int numsSize, int target, int* returnSize) {
    
    int a = 0, b = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < numsSize; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < numsSize; j++) {
            if(nums[i] + nums[j] == target) {
                a = i;
                b = j;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    returnSize* = a;
    *(returnSize + 1) = b;

    return returnSize;
}
int main() {
    int num = 0;
    int* nums[4] = {2,7,11,15};
    int numsSize = 4;
    int* returnSize[2];
    int target = 9;

    num = twoSum(nums, numsSize, target, returnSize);

    printf("Resultado: %i \n", num);

    free(myArray);

    return 0;
}
```

I don't know how to proceed though cuz I don't remember how to return the array values I'm filling this array:
I appreciate any help

Comment: `returnSize* = a` should be `returnSize[0] = a`. And `*(returnSize + 1) = b` can (and I recommend it to) be `returnSize[1] = b`.

Comment: Also, `num = twoSum(...)` should give you a warning, since you try to assign a *pointer* to a non-pointer variable.

Comment: Oh, and `int* returnSize[2];` should be `int returnSize[2];`. That should also have given you a warning.

Comment: And there's no variable named `myArray`, so `free(myArray);` will lead to a build *error*.

Comment: Finally about the values that are "returned", they will be stored in `returnSize[0]` and `returnSize[1]` (once you fix all the above problems).

Comment: There's actually another *possible* problem, with the loops. But for that you need to use a [*debugger*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to figure out.

Comment: Oh and `nums` is wrongly defined as well. You need to take a *lot* of steps back, and start over with your beginners materials.

Comment: has no functional consequences here, but understand that `break` only breaks out of the inner loop. It looks like you want to break out of both at that point, you can do `i = numsSize` and then `break`, or add that entire double loop to a new function and replace `break` with `return`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return an array from a function, *you can't*. You can return a *pointer* to an `int`, which may be the first element of an `int` array. If the array is created within the function, it must be dynamically allocated so that it's lifetime survives the function.

Since you pass in a pointer to the beginning of an array allocated in `main`, this is not an issue.

You do have a syntax error in your code:

> ```
>     returnSize* = a;
>     *(returnSize + 1) = b;
> ```

Better to simplify this to:

```
    returnSize[0] = a;
    returnSize[1] = b;
```

But you also have a logical error. Your `break` will only escape the inner loop, and the outer loop will continue. We can replace this with the following, with the condition returning immediately from the function.

If nothing is found, return a sentinel values `-1` for both indices.

```
int* twoSum(int* nums, int numsSize, int target, int* returnSize) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numsSize; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < numsSize; j++) {
            if (nums[i] + nums[j] == target) {
                returnSize[0] = i;
                returnSize[1] = j;
                return returnSize;
            }
        }
    }

    returnSize[0] = -1;
    returnSize[1] = -1;
    return returnSize;
}
```

A further tweak would be that your inner loop doesn't need to iterate over every element. Only those after the first item. And the outer loop doesn't need to iterate to the end.

```
int* twoSum(int* nums, int numsSize, int target, int* returnSize) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numsSize - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < numsSize; j++) {
            if (nums[i] + nums[j] == target) {
                returnSize[0] = i;
                returnSize[1] = j;
                return returnSize;
            }
        }
    }

    returnSize[0] = -1;
    returnSize[1] = -1;
    return returnSize;
}
```

This ensures that it we searched `{2, 7, 11, 15}` for a target value of `4`, we wouldn't get `{0, 0}` which would be an invalid result as it doesn't point to two different indices.